# About morphisms to the direct sum of modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, projective-module

There is a well-known property of the vector spaces: for every vector $v \in V$ there exists (maybe, it isn't unique) basis $\mathcal B \subset V$ such that $v \in \mathcal B$.

It means that for every element $w$ of the direct sum (maybe, infinite) $V^{\oplus I} := V \oplus V \oplus V$ ... $\oplus V \oplus$ ... ($I$ is some set of indexes) there is a morphism $\phi: V \to V^{\oplus I}$ such that $w \in \operatorname{Im}\phi$.

I want to use this property for the modules (maybe, over the non-commutative ring) but I don't know, true or false is it...

My question:

> Let $P$ be a projective module over a ring $R$. Is it true that for every element $x$ of the direct sum (maybe, infinite) $P^{\oplus I} := P \oplus P \oplus P$ ... $\oplus P \oplus$ ... ($I$ is some set of indexes) there is a morphism $\phi: P \to P^{\oplus I}$ such that $x \in \operatorname{Im}\phi$?

UPD: As Eric Wofsey said, it's enough to prove this fact only for $I = {1, 2}$: the simple induction'll finish our work for finite $I$'s. The case of infinite $I$ is also simple: every element of $P^{\oplus I}$ is contained in some finite direct sum, so the previous part of argument works. But what to do if $|I|=2$? I don't know...

Comment: That is an oddly specific interpretation of what the first paragraph says.. but ok.

Comment: @rschwieb Why have you deleted your answer?

Comment: Because once I wrote it up, i saw why it didn't quite work!  The reasoning I was using only works for free modules.

Comment: I don't immediately see a replacement for what you describe for projective modules. I'm not sure which elements can be part of "bases."

Comment: @rschwieb This fact was one of the parts of my proof of the big theorem and in this proof, $P$ was a projective module. So I decided to write here all of the data I had:-)

Comment: @darijgrinberg I wasn't sure how you descend from the homomorphism into $F^{(I)}$  to get something mapping to the prescribed element.

Comment: There is no need to consider infinite $I$, since any element of $P^{\oplus I}$ is contained in a $P^{\oplus F}$ for some finite $F\subseteq I$.

Comment: In fact, it suffices to consider the case of $P^2$, since you can then bootstrap up to $P^n$ for any finite $n$ (apply the result with $P^2$ in place of $P$ to get up to $P^4$, and so on).

Comment: @EricWofsey You're right. I've edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not true.  For instance, let $R$ be an integral domain that has a nonprincipal invertible ideal $P\subset R$ generated by two elements $a$ and $b$ (e.g., $R=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$, $P=(2,1+\sqrt{-5})$).  I then claim that the element $(a,b)\in P^2$ is not in the image of any homomorphism $f:P\to P^2$.  Indeed, every homomorphism $P\to P$ is given by multiplication by some element of $R$, and so there must be elements $r,s\in R$ such that $f(x)=(rx,sx)$ for all $x\in P$.  If $f(x)=(a,b)$, then this means $a$ and $b$ are both multiples of $x$ which then means that $x$ generates $P$.  Since $P$ is nonprincipal, this is a contradiction.

Comment: Bad news... But thank you very much!